# CSS is not getting applied to jinja2 templates

Tags: css, html, flask, jinja2

I am not able to apply the CSS to the jinja2 templates.
I think it should work, but dont know where i am missing it.

**My Layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <title>
        {% block title %} {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-9'>
                {% block body %} {% endblock %}
            </div>      
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                Menu
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home page:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 min-data">
            My Lappy - DELL VOSTRO          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 min-data">
            <img class="pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/360x203">
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**The CSS file:**

```
.min-data {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The Home page is rendered properly but the the background color is not getting applied as green in the div in the home page.

Comment: Are you sure the file is being loaded by the browser correctly? Is `style.css` in `static`?

Comment: @dirn: I see that i was not getting any error in page load. I cleared the cache and reloaded the page, and it worked fine. And now every time, for the CSS to work, I am clearing the cache. What could be the issue?

Comment: [There are quite a few ways to tell your browser to load the changed file.](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to Chrome browser for this issue. Please try another browser like firefox latest version.